# While integration of tapjoy getting Googleplay services error

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, tapjoy

Am working on android project.In that I have to integrate tapjoy sdk.I did all the steps mentioned in Tapjoy - Knowledge center.After my tapjoy integration,I am getting empty white view while running my app.I didnt get any errors.But i am getting a internal exception like

> tapjoy disabled because googleplay service not found

Please help me to sole this.I added already googleplay services to my project.I added the code like

```
TapjoyConnect.requestTapjoyConnect(getApplicationContext(),
 "3bc9e039-47ce-xxxxxxxxxxx",
 "eKouC0EGNyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
 connectFlags,
 new TapjoyConnectNotifier() {
      @Override public void connectSuccess() {
           //The Connect call succeeded 
           Log.i(TAG, "The Connect call succeeded ");
      }
      @Override public void connectFail() {
           //The connect call failed 
           Log.i(TAG, "The connect call failed");
      }
```

In this am getting 'The connect call failed' log text.What I have to chage?

Comment: I/TapjoyLog(3224): enableLogging: true
 I/TapjoyConnect(3224): Metadata successfully loaded
 W/ResourceType(3224): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
E/TapjoyConnect(3224): IntegrationException: Tapjoy SDK is disabled because Google Play Services was not found. For more information about including the Google Play services client library visit http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html or http://tech.tapjoy.com/product-overview/sdk-change-log/tapjoy-and-identifiers
 I/5555555555555555555(3224): The connect call failed

Comment: Google Play Service was not found because i think you are testing it on Genymotion or any Emulator that has no GAPPS installed, try testing it on a real device which has google play store installed

Comment: thanks for your reply..But am testing it in my micromax mobile which is having playstore.

Comment: Did you add the google-play-service to your project's reference library? it is working fine with me , i have demo, i can mail you if you want